# Javascript External Script Execution

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that I added in `index.html` before closing head tag.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var es = document.createElement('script');
        es.type = 'text/javascript';
        es.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/javascript/js/external.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(es, s);
    })();


    // This one works
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        test();
    });

    // this one triggers error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"
    test();
</script>
```

Here is the code for `external.js` file:

```
(function(window) {
    window.test = function() {
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
})(window);
```

I need explanation about why `test()` function triggers error when I call it outside `load` event?

Comment: It seems to work when the `src` is changed to a hard-coded assignment to `textContent`, but that's probably not what you want

Comment: I am not sure, but seems src has nothing to do with ""Uncaught ReferenceError" issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem too surprising to me. The call to test that fails occurs before the script has had time to load. The one that succeeds happens after the delay it takes for the window to load, which is also probably enough time for the script to load -- loading that script might even be considered something that has to finish before the window is considered loaded.

Comment: `<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->`

Could you explain why `ga` function is available without `load` event?

Comment: @kshetline here is the screenshot of google analytics integration code for better understanding. 
https://i.gyazo.com/f2bba4bbe4c066f151b2d31d70af0d46.png

I need the explanation why it works here but not for me. Thanks!

Comment: It works in that screenshot because the function is being added in the same script tag, where as you probably (since you don't show it I'm just assuming) import your external script in a separate script tag. Since they are assigning the ga function in the same code block, it is immediately available. Meanwhile, you will need to make sure that your other script has loaded and executed before you can use it, which is pretty much the purpose of the load event I would guess.

Comment: [load event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) states that the load event "is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading" meaning when your html document has loaded and all of it's other resources, including your external script, have finished loading. This is why it works in the load event, because that event indicates that your external script has loaded and thus the function assignment has been completed.

Comment: That obfuscated Google code is hard to read! I see obermillerk commented by time I finished plowing through it, but that `ga` function is defined within that script immediately, it's not a function that has to wait for the external JavaScript to be loaded before it's defined.